# Why is GetFieldValue returning null for this DateTime?

Tags: c#, parsing, datatable

I have a DataTable whose data is being fed into a Class:

```
MyProperty = myDataRow.GetFieldValue("MyPropertyColumn", DataUtils.NullDateTime);
```

Property **MyProperty** is a **Nullable DateTime** and the value of the column is:

```
'2010-09-27 00:00:00.000'   AS 'MyPropertyColumn',
```

When the debugger steps over the first line of code above, MyProperty is null when I expect it to be set to the DateTime from the DataTable. Is there any reason why this date isn't being parsed correctly?

Comment: since that is a string and NOT a DateTime it is subject to parsing which in turn depends several settings... why aren't you using a DateTime ?

Comment: What is the type of the table column? Is it a text type like VARCHAR or a date type?

Comment: I switched the value of the column to GETDATE() and it worked so it seems to be an issue with typing. So then I set my column to "CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-09-27 00:00:00.000')" and it worked.

Comment: `System.Data.DataRow` has no method called `GetFieldValue`. How is `GetFieldValue` defined? Is it an extension method that you have written?

Comment: Olivier - you're right it is an extension method. I didn't realize it because it was from a referenced library. Maybe I should delete this question since it is a very specific case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column value needs to be passed in as a DateTime and not a string, thus:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-09-27 00:00:00.000') AS 'MyPropertyColumn',
```